# ComboBox inputbox causes reselection of range

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I'm working on a userform prompting an inputbox for a range whenever the combobox dropdown button is clicked.

The problem is that whenever the range is selected (selecting a cell and then clicking ok), the userform is unselected (greys out), shows an empty dropdown list and forces me to reselect a range after I click anywhere on the workbook.

**Is there any way to prevent a re selection of a range when clicking the dropdown button?**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Code Below:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    Dim InputCell As Range
    Set InputCell = Application.InputBox("Select Lookup Cell", "Obtain Object Range", Type:=8)
    ComboBox1.Text = InputCell.Address(0, 0, external:=True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can anyone help me format this question? I have no idea why but I'm unable to add pictures. It tells me to indent my code... @PeterT Much appreciated.

Comment: Nothing but problems with the RefEdit Object!

Comment: It seems that the `DropButtonClick` event gets fired twice, once on the way in and once on the way out...hence the issue.

Comment: Even removing the frames, which usually causes issues, is of no help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've used the `RefEdit` object in the past, I used the real thing (which I know has it's issues) and just used the `Change` event.

Perhaps you could just use the `Enter` event (you just have to ignore it the first time, if's it the first object that gets focus when initialized)

***Resources:***

**[Using RefEdit Controls in Excel
Dialogs](https://peltiertech.com/using-refedit-controls-in-excel-dialogs/) - Jon Peltier**

> **RefEdits must be placed directly on the UserForm itself.** If you put a
> RefEdit in a frame or on a multipage, strange things will happen,
> including bizarre Excel crashes.
>
> **RefEdits must not be used on modeless forms.** RefEdits on modeless
> forms will result in bizarre Excel crashes.
>
> **RefEdit event procedures should be avoided.** RefEdit events do not
> behave reliably, and they may result in VBA errors which are difficult
> to debug.
>
> **References to RefEdits must be removed.** When a UserForm is added to a
> VB project, Excel adds a reference to the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object
> Library. This reference is required for proper operation of the
> UserForms in your project. To see what references your project has,
> select the project in the Project Explorer, then select References
> from the Tools menu.

**[Alternative to Excel’s Flaky RefEdit Control](https://peltiertech.com/refedit-control-alternative/) - Jon Peltier**

> The new approach uses a TextBox in the dialog instead of the RefEdit.
>
> The TextBox does not interact directly with a range as does the RefEdit. Instead, when this drop button is clicked, the dialog is temporarily hidden, and an InputBox appears to solicit the user’s input.
>
> "It may be tempting to use type 8 to indicate a range object, but there
> is an obscure glitch that causes it to fail when the worksheet
> contains conditional formatting conditions that use formulas in their
> definitions. Fortunately using Type 0 to specify a formula works just
> fine."

**[Cannot use keyboard shortcuts to select ranges in RefEdit control in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291110)**

Comment: I must first say that I didn't know that combo boxes were part of the RefEdit object. Otherwise, I think I'll move away from the combo boxes to encounter less issues. Thanks for the 2nd resource.

Answer (score 0):

From this source: [Ozgrid](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/100576-combobox-change-event-firing-multiple-times)

Though I'll be using custom text boxes, this could also work if anyone wants to use the combo boxes.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    Static Abort As Boolean

    If Abort Then Exit Sub
    Abort = False

    Dim InputCell As Range
    Set InputCell = Application.InputBox("Select Lookup Cell", "Obtain Object Range", Type:=8)

    ComboBox1.Text = InputCell.Address(0, 0, external:=True)

    Abort = True
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, `Set InputCell =...` will error if the user cancels input.  This if one of the only times where you need to wrap it with `On Error Resume Next`.  Then you can check `If Not InputCell is Nothing Then` and continue setting the address.